# How to set axios token for client side in nuxt server init?

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

I'm trying to authenticate my user when the page is loading. So I have the following code :

```
actions: {
      nuxtServerInit ({dispatch, commit, app}, context) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const cookies = cparse.parse(context.req.headers.cookie || '')
          if (cookies.hasOwnProperty('x-access-token')) {
            app.$axios.setToken(cookies['x-access-token'], 'Bearer')
            api.auth.me2()
              .then(result => {
                commit('setUser', result.data.user)
                resolve(true)
              })
              .catch(error => {
                commit('resetUser')
                resetAuthToken()
                resolve(false)
              })
          } else {
            resetAuthToken()
            resolve(false)
          }
        })
      }
```

However I have the following error : 
Cannot read $axios property of undefined. What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Interesting -- I was wondering where to modify axios for cookies. But how come this doesn't run on the server? Just because of the promise? Is that guaranteed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App should come from context e.g. from second argument.
So your code should be

```
context.app.$axios.setToken(cookies['x-access-token'], 'Bearer')
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way. You could pass `app` in the second argument such that

```
nuxtServerInit ({dispatch, commit}, {app}) {
```

The complete code:

```
actions: {
  nuxtServerInit ({dispatch, commit}, {app}) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const cookies = cparse.parse(context.req.headers.cookie || '')
      if (cookies.hasOwnProperty('x-access-token')) {
        app.$axios.setToken(cookies['x-access-token'], 'Bearer')
        api.auth.me2()
          .then(result => {
            commit('setUser', result.data.user)
            resolve(true)
          })
          .catch(error => {
            commit('resetUser')
            resetAuthToken()
            resolve(false)
          })
      } else {
        resetAuthToken()
        resolve(false)
      }
    })
  }
}
```